# SQLITE_IOEERR: in Meteor

Tags: linux, meteor

```
Retrying after error { [Error: SQLITE_IOERR: disk I/O error] errno: 10, code:
'SQLITE_IOERR' }
Retrying after error { [Error: SQLITE_IOERR: disk I/O error] errno: 10, code:
'SQLITE_IOERR' }
/home/kdibbs/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2.1r0536n++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:190
      throw error;
      ^

Error: SQLITE_IOERR: disk I/O error
    at Error (native)
 => awaited here:
    at Promise.await (/home/kdibbs/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2.1r0536n++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:39:12)
    at Db._execute (/tools/packaging/catalog/catalog-remote.js:355:8)
    at /tools/packaging/catalog/catalog-remote.js:144:10
    at Db._retry (/tools/packaging/catalog/catalog-remote.js:156:16)
    at new Db (/tools/packaging/catalog/catalog-remote.js:143:8)
    at RemoteCatalog.initialize (/tools/packaging/catalog/catalog-remote.js:694:15)
    at /tools/cli/main.js:815:20
```

So I ran this meteor program a few days ago, then I made a few more users and a group on my machine..All of which didn't affect my normal user...And now I'm getting this error? Any clues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try searching for this? Looking at the SQLite reference here https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#ioerr

It sounds like one of your disks is giving an error - something like too many files open, or perhaps it's getting full?

> (10) SQLITE_IOERR
>
> The SQLITE_IOERR result code says that the operation could not finish
>   because the operating system reported an I/O error. A full disk drive
>   will normally give an SQLITE_FULL error rather than an SQLITE_IOERR
>   error.
>
> There are many different extended result codes for I/O errors that
>   identify the specific I/O operation that failed.

Comment: Thanks, I think that is what happened because I'm using a VM thanks alot man.